# accept or decline with reaction but it doesn't work discord.js v13 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wanna send the suggestion to a channel with two reaction then if the admin reacted ✅ send it to another channel and if ❌ delete it.
I tried this but first it can't send embed it says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'discord')` and I tried without embed and I used reactions but doesn't work

**Code:**

```
module.exports = {
name: "suggest",
category: "Suggestion",
description: "suggest something",
usage: "suggest [text]",
owner: false,
execute(message, args, client) {
    message.reply({ content: "..." }).then(async(msg) => {
        const sug = args[0];
        const suggestion = args.join(" ");
        if (!sug) {
            message.delete();
            msg.edit({
                content: `[ You did not provide a suggestion ]`,
            })
        } else {
                const acceptch = message.guild.channels.cache.get('980126282719313970');
                if (err) {
                    message.delete();
                    msg.edit({
                        content: `[ ${err} ]`,
                    })
                } else {
                    const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('0b9494')
                        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                        .setDescription(suggestion)
                    acceptch.send(embed)
                        .then(msg => {
                            msg.react('✅').then(() => msg.react('❌'));

                            msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == '746917945065865376' && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == '❌'), { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
                                .then(collected => {
                                    const reaction = collected.first();
                                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                                        return message.author.send('**no**')
                                    }
                                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                                        message.channel.send(`suggestion: ${suggestion}`)
                                    }
                                });
                        }).catch(console.error);
                }
        }

    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in discord js v13 we can't use `acceptch.send(embed)` anymore as they said in [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc) we have to send embeds like this `acceptch.send({ embeds: [embed] });`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the discord.js [documentation for "Client" class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), there is no such thing as `client.discord`.

Which is why this line `const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()` from your code throws error, because your are trying to access property "MessageEmbed" of object that is undefined.

You can add `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')` at the beginning of that file and then just use `const embed = new MessageEmbed()`.

Comment: actually in discord js v13 we have to make embeds like this `new client.discord.MessageEmbed()`

Comment: And you say that based on what? I literally linked official documentation that says otherwise. In that v13 guide you linked in your own aswer there is a line `const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Attachments');` one block below the code you referenced in your answer. Not to mention, that the error message clearly states that in this code `client.discord` is undefined and you can't read it's properties.